# nodemailer mail options from: field is always sending mail from the email used in the smtpTrans auth object

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to do contact forms and mailing things.

But when I try to set the req.body.email as the from: email it just uses the authentication email instead. So all emails I receive are from: me@me.com to: me@me.com

instead of from: customer@them.com to: me@me.com

I'm pretty sure I'm doing it right

```
var mailOpts, smtpTrans;

  //Setup Nodemailer transport, I chose gmail. Create an routerlication-specific password to avoid problems.
  smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'Gmail',
      auth: {
        user: "me@me.com",
        pass: "hey"
      }
  });
  //Mail options
    console.log(req.body.email);
  mailOpts = {
      from: req.body.email, //grab form data from the request body object
      to: 'me@me.com',
      subject: 'Stockist interest form',
      text: "Welcome to the My Leisure Stockists application process, we'd love to have you on board"+"\n Email: "+req.body.email
  };

  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {

      if (error) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
      } else {
        res.sendStatus(200);
      };

  });
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you ever figure it out? Or is that the expected behavior?

Comment: @MichaelLynch No actually I'm still using the solution of including "Email: "+req.body.email inside the text: property so that we can get the emails through. 

I don't think this is expected behaviour as I swear that when I first installed nodemailer it was setting from from: email address to the req.body.email 

Not any more though, we should submit a bug report

Comment: Have you figured this out now? I'm having the same exact issue.

Comment: even I am also having this issue

Comment: I think they fixed it... some how, it works now?

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

First you need something like bodyparser. As 2019 yo can use:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Obviusly first use express:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

The other thing is that is a text field so you put it in a string. As in es6 notation you can use:

```
`${req.body.email}`
```

So you get something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

const smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
      user: "me@me.com",
      pass: "hey"
    }
});

app.post('/send-email', function (req, res) {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `${req.body.email}`, // Sender address
    to: 'me@me.com',         // List of recipients
    subject: 'Stockist interest form',
    text: "Welcome to the My Leisure Stockists application process, we'd love to have you on board"+"\n Email: "+req.body.email
  };

  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
  });

  res.redirect("/index.html");
})
```

Comment: Bruh, this is totally irrelevant